# Rank correlation over time for Zipf-like distribution

Tags: time-series, correlation, ranking, zipf

I've got 14 years of city population data. I wish to get an idea of how much the ranking of cities by population size changes over time. Is it stable or unstable? I guess if there's not much difference between city sizes, changes in ranking would not be very significant, and conversely. Since city sizes follow a Zipf-type distribution, size differences tend to be large among the biggest cities and small or nil among the smallest. Thus, ranking volatility in the upper ranks would be significant, but insignificant in the lower ranks. So, perhaps, rank should be weighted by city-size? Is it valid to do a rank correlation between the first and last years (by which method) and somehow combine that with weighting? Or is there an entirely different way?